# Order of the error-handling and 404-handling middlewares?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

The express.js website confused me, because there are two contradictory statements:

> **You define error-handling middleware last,** after other app.use() and routes calls
> – [/guide/error-handling.html](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html)

and

> All you need to do is add a middleware function at the **very bottom of the stack (below all other functions)** to handle a 404 response
> – [/starter/faq.html](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/faq.html)

It seems to be telling me that both of these middleware layers should be the last ones in the stack...? Erm, so what, I am meant to add two `app.use` middleware layers last? That is not possible...

---

Anyway, obviously one of these pages forgot to mention the exception of the other, so I'd like to know: which middleware should I register last? My error-handler or my 404-handler?

### I'd like these two functions, but I'm not sure which order they need to go in for express to work properly:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.status(404).send('Sorry cant find that!');
});

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err.stack);
  res.status(500).send('Something broke!');
});
```

Also I'm wondering, do I need to call `next` from within either handler?

Answer (score 0):

The order doesn't really matter as your last middleware only gets called, when in some middleware before `next(err)` has been called. Your 404 middleware will always get called if nothing else has handled (and finished) the request.

And for your second question: no, you don't want to call `next()`in either of those as you finish the request with `res.send()`.

Edit: I would leave the order like that though as the 404 middleware is not really an error handler.